# Browsers does not render text correctly

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, render

Does anyone know, why the letter alignment is so different at 100% to 500% zoom and gets better when I zoom in?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mmayv8fgslhbp93/chrome-font-100p.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/q447r1t6t27vgby/chrome-font-500p.png

(there are the same issues in firefox)

I certainly want the 100% version to look like the "overzoomed" one.

So hopefully you can help me.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: paste here the CSS of the menu bar

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nYAH6

Answer (score 0):

Try `font-weight:500;` in `#header`

Comment: tried it, but it doesn't change anything :/ when I set the value to 100, I get my result (only in firefox), but the font looks more like a light font ...

Comment: it exposes, when I use "Helvetica CE Regular", it looks the way, I wanted it to look. Maybe it's just in font ...
but thank you anyway :)